# ExtJS 4.x: How to disable the red mark BUT only in runtime

Tags: extjs, grid

I can't find solution. I want to leave "red corner" when user update grid cell (and to remove red corner now is quite easy - in afretedit call data.record.commit()) but I don't know how to do it in runtime. I meke some loops to calculate something (sum of raw e.g.) and this value I want to write in one, special cell but WITHOUT RED MARK. 
Be so kind to prompt me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I found proper soolution. Good way is to read manual, I just commited store of this grid after described above loops:

```
    store.commitChanges()
```